# Plotting discrete data as a line graph

Tags: matlab, plot, line-plot

I am trying to simulate a real time plot in MATLAB in order to display an ECG signal. I am trying to test my idea with a small data set. I have created a matrix called Y containing values from 0 to 25*pi, and wish to plot sin(Y), with each data point being plotted as if it is in real time. This is the code I have written:

```
Y= [0:0.1:25*pi];
X = sin(Y);
[a,b] = size(Y);

for i = 1:b
hold on;
line(i,X(i));
drawnow;
pause(0.01);
end
```

This works well and the resulting graph moves as in "real time", however due to the discrete nature of the data set it plots single points instead of a smooth line. I was wondering if there is a way to convert the current graph output into something resembling a smooth line plot? Thank you in advance for any help on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try doing

```
 plot(1:i,X(1:i));
```

instead of

```
 line(i,X(i));
```

Edit: You wouldn't need to do hold on; with this method either.

Answer (score 0):

Try using plot instead of line. For example,

```
plot(1:i, X(1:i), 'k-x');
```

plots a solid black line with cross markers.

This can be quite slow as the graph is plotted over and over. With `hold on`, one could instead plot just the last line segment:

```
plot(i-1:i, X(i-1:i), 'k-x');
```